# Migrating from Junit to TestNG

Tags: java, maven, junit, testng

I need to migrate a bunch of test scripts from Junit to TestNG , So is there any utility or a runner does TestNG provides to run Junit test scripts ? also I am currently using Maven .

If possible Can someone share the snippet on how to do it .

Comment: Why the migration, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I am trying parallel execution , I tried with Junit  and maven surefire plugin with classes as parallel , I found the test methods within a class is running concurrently and so the results seems not fine , so i want to give a try with TestNG as it is preffered in most cases for parallel  . Any feasible solution available to use TestNG for Junit without porting Junit annotations .

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it is a very old post, but I hope this would be useful if anyone is looking to migrate to TestNG.

I have a spring application and my JUnit tests uses different runners and tags like 
 - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
 - PowerMockRunner
 - EasyMockRunner 
 - @ContextConfiguration.

Junit works with @RunWith tag where as TestNG requires extending classes AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests(for @ContextConfiguration), PowerMockTestCase(for PowerMockRunner), ..etc. Though there were multiple options provided(extending, configuration, other annotations) in some cases, some of the options didn't work and extending only worked. If the test class requires extending it may not work for some tests as the test might be already extending another base class and you need to refactor the tests and it may not be worth.

My 2 cents is that JUnit5 has some of the missing Junit4 features of TestNG and see if that solves the problem before jumping to migrating to TestNG.

Answer (score -1):

**The official document** for Migrating from Juit to TestNG can be found [here](http://testng.org/doc/migrating.html). Please take a look.